# can i Change jitsi front-end and download from own repository

Tags: jitsi, jitsi-meet

I want to some changes in jitsi and install from my own repository.
Actually after some changes, i want to install it in many servers with each servers have unique domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the front-end with two options :

**Option 1 (recommended)**

Follow the [manual installation documentation](https://jitsi.github.io/handbook/docs/devops-guide/devops-guide-manual) and replace «jitsi-meet» component which is in /srv/jitsi-meet

This directory must contain your version of [jitsi-meet](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet.git) (you must build the project, follow [this step](https://jitsi.github.io/handbook/docs/devops-guide/devops-guide-manual#deploy-jitsi-meet) but clone your repository instead official repository)

**Option 2 (not recommended)**

Follow the [quick installation](https://jitsi.github.io/handbook/docs/devops-guide/devops-guide-quickstart) then replace the /usr/share/jitsi-meet

This is [the same step](https://jitsi.github.io/handbook/docs/devops-guide/devops-guide-manual#deploy-jitsi-meet) but in another directory

Be careful, this option is faster but each update on jisti-meet package (apt) can break your installation and override the /usr/share/jitsi-meet directory